# Why isn't the bottom of my page Block table being rendered?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

The bottom of my table is being cut off, and I don't know why. It's a VF page embedded in between sections on in a page layout.

Any ideas/advice?

Here is the code.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Support Tickets">
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Cases}" var="c">
  <apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">Support Ticket</apex:facet>
     <apex:outputLink value="/{!c.id}">{!c.caseNumber}</apex:outputLink>
  </apex:column>

  <apex:column >
     <apex:facet name="header">Subject</apex:facet>
     <apex:outputLink value="/{!c.id}">{!c.subject}</apex:outputLink>
  </apex:column>

  <apex:column >
     <apex:facet name="header">Created Date</apex:facet>{!c.createdDate}
  </apex:column>

 <apex:column >
   <apex:facet name="header">Status</apex:facet>{!c.Status}
 </apex:column>        
</apex:pageBlockTable>        
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely this limitation is the actual height of your page layout. This can be changed in the page layout configuration and not from within code. Your page is living in an IFrame with a fixed size controlled by the page layout itself, and not determined by the page(s) contained within it.

Go to: Name|Setup|Customize|Cases (assuming you're extending the Cases object)|Page Layouts|Edit. Click on Visualforce Pages to show your custom page and then click the wrench in the upper right.

[image: VF page properties]

If you don't see this or can't get to this section of Salesforce, talk with your admin to get access.

Comment: how do i do that? I can tell you it happens at certain resolutions and not at others if that helps. I'm very new o this front end stuff....

Comment: or alternatitavely, how do i add a vertical scroll bar?